# Make rotating proxies both HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: haproxy

I am using mattes's rotating proxy docker container from GitHub -> https://github.com/mattes/rotating-proxy

I've setup everything correctly and it is running perfectly.

However, it is acting as a HTTPS proxy only and not both HTTP and HTTPS.

I've changed the HAProxy config file and set the `mode` from `http` to `tcp` but it is still HTTPS only.

This is my current `haproxy.cfg.erb` file which is changed to `haproxy.cfg` later using a Ruby script:

```
global
  maxconn 1024000 
  daemon
  pidfile <%= pid_file %>

defaults
  mode tcp
  maxconn 1024000
  option  tcplog
  option  dontlognull
  retries 3
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client 60s
  timeout server 60s


listen stats *:4444
  mode            http
  log             global
  maxconn 1024000
  clitimeout      100s
  srvtimeout      100s
  contimeout      100s
  timeout queue   100s
  stats enable
  stats hide-version
  stats refresh 30s
  stats show-node
  stats uri /haproxy?stats


frontend rotating_proxies
  bind *:<%= port %>
  mode tcp
  default_backend tor
  option http_proxy
  option tcplog

backend tor
  option http_proxy
  option tcplog
  mode tcp
  balance leastconn # http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#balance

  <% backends.each do |b| %>
  server <%= b[:name] %><%= b[:port] %> <%= b[:addr] %>:<%= b[:port] %>
  <% end %>
```

I am using http://www.checker.freeproxy.ru/checker/ and it says the proxy type is HTTPS only.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the scripts you're trying to us (TOR rotating proxies) are simply using the TOR bridges to get you a new proxy on each request.

Well, you've to know that TOR is SOCKS only and this is clear on the README file of the GitHub repository you're trying to use.

> Please note: Tor offers a SOCKS Proxy only. In order to allow
>   communication from HAproxy to Tor, Polipo is used to translate from
>   HTTP proxy to SOCKS proxy. HAproxy is able to talk to HTTP proxies
>   only.

And the answer of @usamember is totally useless and you might notice that you've already breaked your HAProxy configuration by following his answer. Now you should receive "504: Connection refused"

---

However, there's an alternative to TOR. See this GitHub repository: https://github.com/jgontrum/proxies-rotator

It uses GimmeProxy.com's API to get proxies and rotate them on your client. So this is an alternative to TOR

Comment: I second using gimmeproxy.com - it's very nice rotating proxy API.

Answer (score 0):

In your backend `tor` you have this option:

```
option http_proxy
```

You've to remove this line. Also this proxies checker that you're using will always say `HTTPS` because this is a rotating proxies client.